# having trouble with fread function in the code

Tags: c

I wrote a program in C to open bitmap image and save the dimension the image. i am having some problem to write the fread function. please tell me what should be the correct format for the function in the code that i have written
is there something wrong with the code?

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void fskip(FILE *fp, int num_bytes)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<num_bytes; i++)
      fgetc(fp);
}

typedef struct tagBITMAP              /* The structure for a bitmap. */
{
 int width;
 int height;
 //unsigned char *data;
} BITMAP;


int main()
{
    int temp1=0;
    BITMAP *bmp[50];

    FILE *fp = fopen("splash.bmp","rb");

    if (fp!=NULL && (fgetc(fp[count])=='B' && fgetc(fp[count])=='M')){
    bmp[temp1] = (BITMAP *) malloc (sizeof(BITMAP));

    fskip(fp,16);
    fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);

    fskip(fp,2);
    fread(&bmp[temp1].height,sizeof(int), 1, fp);



     fclose(fp);
     }
     else exit(0);

     getch();

     }
```

Comment: Could you please change the indentation of the code so it fits in the window and also remove the c++ tag if this is pure c.

Comment: What is the error it's crashing with? Is it segfaulting?

Comment: a message flashes : "bitmap.exe has stopped working"

but it successfully compiles and runs in separate parts

Comment: In my experience, "has stopped working" means segfault on Windows.

Comment: is there something wrong with the code??

Comment: I have no problem compiling and running the code under Windows 7 using Netbeans/MinGW GCC (although I had to add the includes for stdlib.h and stdio.h). I can enter the image paths and it tells me if the image dimensions mismatch as expected.

Comment: Did you change "%s" to "%c" in all 3 `scanf("%s",&choice)`?  Also recommend changing to " %c" instead of "%c".

Comment: I've changed it already. But its still not working. Its giving the same error during run time : "bitmap.exe has stopped working"

Comment: try debugging and figure out what line it crashes. Having said that, for opening a bitmap you should open the file with fopen(file, "rb");

Comment: the code crashes at the first 'fread' function is called.
is it wrong ??

Comment: did you give it correct file path?  You are not handling non-existant files correctly.

Comment: the file path is correct.

Comment: Your statement "the program stops unexpectedly" seems to directly answer your question "is there something wrong with the code?"

Comment: Why aren't you checking to see if `fopen` succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

2 problems.

```
if (fp!=NULL && (fgetc(fp[count])=='B' && fgetc(fp[count])=='M')){
```

should be

```
if (fp!=NULL && (fgetc(fp)=='B' && fgetc(fp)=='M')){
```

You are "skipping" the wrong amount

```
// read 1 integer (likely size 4)
fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
// Skip 2 bytes
fskip(fp,2);
// read another integer (likely size 4)
fread(&bmp[temp1].height,sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

One solution

```
fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
// Don't skip - you are in the right location.
fread(&bmp[temp1].height,sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Better solution

```
typedef struct tagBITMAP              /* The structure for a bitmap. */
{
   uint32_t width;
   uint32_t height;
} BITMAP;

fread(&bmp[temp1].width, sizeof(bmp[temp1].width) , 1, fp);
fread(&bmp[temp1].height,sizeof(bmp[temp1].height), 1, fp);
```